# MySql soterd procedure IF ELSE and while loop

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure in MySQL where I loop through the records and return rows if certain condition is true.

For eg: I have a table with columns `PRIMARY, TRANSTYPE, DATE, AMOUNT`. Now `PRIMARY` can be either 0 or 1 and `TRANSTYPE` can BE A,B,C.

Now what I want to do is return row where 
`PRIMARY="0" if TRANSTYPE = "A" and return row where PRIMARY="1" if TRANSTYPE = "B" or TRANSTYPE = "C"`

Currently I am doing this with PHP, but I want to do it with MySql stored procedure.

Comment: Can you put some more light on your question. what is table structure and query!!  did you try out something?         http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME()
    BEGIN
       select * from table
       where (TRANSTYPE = 'A' and PRIMARY = '0') 
          or (TRANSTYPE in ('B','C') and PRIMARY = '1');
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
    WHERE
         (PRIMARY="0" AND TRANSTYPE = "A") OR 
         (PRIMARY="1" AND TRANSTYPE = "B") OR 
         (PRIMARY="1" AND TRANSTYPE = "C")
```